# TFS webtest for SSRS reports issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, webtest, axd

I am creating webtests in TFS and trying to test reports execution in SSRS. When I record the initial process, it includes Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd files. These files are what is causing the problem.

When I remove the files, the report does not display, however if I keep the AXD files in it works fine. The problem with keeping the AXD files is the reportsession querystring variable that are included. If I run the report after a bit the reportsession has obviously changed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the AXD files are necessary as it is what actually displays the report. The reportsession, controlid and cache seed need to be set as dynamic properties and passed into a contect variable. From there you can reference that context variable in the other AXD requests. There is also a single reporturl querystring variable that needs to be captured as well. Once those were set up correctly it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

can you convert the test to a coded test. Then you should be able to interrogate the Context.LastResponse.ResponseUri.Query after you yield the request. Store the value you need there and pass it into the request.

Comment: +1 - as this would also work. I found the reason, stated in my answer. Thanks